# How do I read from/write to a binary file in 2D Array form?

Tags: c, arrays, file, binaryfiles, fread

I am trying to use a binary file to hold my data in it. But I don't understand how do I read/write in 2D Array form. I know how to read arrays/structs etc. from binary files, I just don't know how do I do that with a 2D array.

I have looked at similar questions to this, but I did not understand what most of the people were getting at. I just want to know how does one read/write data in 2D Array format. as in fwrite( x , y , z , w ); .

Here is what my array looks like:

```
int array[50][100];
```

I don't know what to do from now on, if it were 1 dimensional I'd do;

```
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("file.bin","wb+");
fwrite(array, sizeof(int), 50, fp);
```

but since that array is multi dimensional I don't actually know what to put in that function.

Thank you in advance.

Please note that I am pretty new at coding and I may not be seeing a pretty easy solution.

Comment: If you read/wrote each element one at a time, you would just need to be sure to read and write following the same pattern.

Comment: Yeah but can't I just read it as a whole? I mean you can read arrays as a whole right?

Comment: If you can be sure that it will read and write in the same pattern, sure.

Comment: Yeah but how? do I do
```
fwrite(array,sizeof(int),50*100,fp);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: When writing information in binary form, you need some scheme to indicate how much data is written, and it what form, incorporated into what is written to the file. If more than one array needs to be written to the file, then an example would be to *Prefix* your data with 9-bytes representing `char int int` where you store the typesize (e.g. the `char` would hold `4` for `sizeof(int)`,) than then the next two `int` would contain the `rows` and `cols` for the array dimensions (for a 1D array `rows=1`). Then you can simply read the 9-bytes and know what comes next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for saving a 2-dimensional array will be very similar to saving a 1-dimensional array, it is indeed as you wrote in the comment to the question:

```
fwrite(array, sizeof(int), 50*100, fp);
```

This is because the 2 dimensional (in this case, `int`)array is stored identically to how a 1 dimensional array would be; an unbroken chain of `int`s. However, you could save it any way you want to as long as you stay consistent with saving/loading. `fwrite` takes *a pointer* as an argument, so as long as the data you pass to it is an array it will work.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Oops, I wrote that fwrite takes an array as an argument, when it is of type void*. I got my explanation mixed into the terminology, post edited accordingly.

Comment: You really helped me out! Thank you :)